# golang html template not properly formatted

Tags: html, go, go-html-template

this might be a very basic question as I am not familiar with web programming at all. I am trying to create a table using html template which content is filled through a go script. My problem is that the  tag does not fall where I intended it to. This is the html used for the html template

```
<h1>Exchange Rate for {{.Title}}</h1>

<form action="/dateShow/react" method="POST">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>From</td>
        <td>To</td>
        <td>Rate</td>
        <td>7-day avg</td>
    </tr>{{.Data}}
</table>
<div><input type="submit" value="Save"></div>
</form>
```

I was expecting that the GO script would print the "data" after the first "tr"tag and inside the "table" tag. Instead, this is what I get

```
<html><head></head><body><h1>Exchange Rate for 2018-07-02</h1>

<form action="/dateShow/react" method="POST">
&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;usd&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;idr&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;15.000000&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;14.238334&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;usd&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;sgd&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;1.320000&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;1.310000&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
<table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>From</td>
        <td>To</td>
        <td>Rate</td>
        <td>7-day avg</td>
    </tr></tbody></table>
<div><input type="submit" value="Save"></div>
</form></body></html>
```

This is so weird to be as the "title" part works fine and landed Where I want it to. But not the case for the body

Comment: Well, HTML has a certain structure. This structure is enforced e.g. by a browser and that's probably what you showed. E.g. the structure requires tbody-tags and those got inserted. If your data does not belong behind a tr tag (well, nothing belongs there except other tr tags) it will get moved. You _must_ generate valid HTML. Without knowing what Data is, it is hard to tell what you dod wrong. Note that if Data contains _preformated_ HTML you have to tell that to html.template via https://godoc.org/html/template#HTML

Comment: Best advice is: Do not render preformated HTML. Make Data a struct or a slice of structs, whatever and let html.template do the heavy work of escaping.

Comment: Thank you for the help, using template.HTML works

Comment: `template.HTML` works but as Volker said, it's very much the wrong solution. Why bother using templates at all if you're passing HTML to them? Render your HTML in the template, not in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the entire slice of exchange rates to the template, and use [`range`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions) to iterate over it.

For example, if you have a struct like:

```
var ExchangeRates []ExchangeRate

type ExchangeRate struct {
    From            string
    To              string
    Rate            float64
    SevenDayAverage float64
}
```

You will pass `ExchangeRates` to the template, and the template might look like:

```
<table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>From</td>
        <td>To</td>
        <td>Rate</td>
        <td>7-day avg</td>
    </tr>
    {{range .ExchangeRates}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{.From}}</td>
        <td>{{.To}}</td>
        <td>{{.Rate}}</td>
        <td>{{.SevenDayAverage}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{end}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```